# e = console.info; not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

So i am lazy and like to give console.info a new function name :) But i also like to be safe and make sure that i can leave my logging in and not error in browsers that don't support console.
So i wrote this:

```
if (typeof console == "object" && typeof console.error == "function") {
    e = console.info; 
}
```

Now the problem only occurs in chrome and get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

To me this seems like a very general error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most likely explanation is that the `console` object's `info` function expects that `this` within the function will be the `console` object. That won't be the case if you do this:

```
var e = console.info;
e("Foo");
```

Remember that in JavaScript, `this` is defined entirely by *how a function is called*, not where it's defined. More: [*Mythical methods*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/mythical-methods.html) and [*You must remember `this`*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/04/you-must-remember-this.html).

You'd have to do this instead:

```
e.call(console, "Foo");
```

...which obviously isn't shorter.

So to do this reliably, you have to create a function instead:

```
function e(msg) {
    console.info(msg);
}
```

jAndy pointed out we can also use `Function#bind` (part of ES5) for this, since Chrome has that and, on Chrome, `console.info` is a real JavaScript function. So:

```
e = console.info.bind(console);
```

That will only work on browsers that support ES5 (so, not IE8 and earlier for instance) and where `console.info` is a *real* JavaScript function (some host-provided functions on some browsers are not, although I think `console.info` is on most if not all). But if you're targeting Chrome, you're golden. Also, `bind` is one of the ES5 features that's trivial to implement in a non-ES5 browser (the [es5-shim.js project](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim) and several others do). But implementing `bind` purely for this one use is probably overkill, just use the `function e(msg) { .. }` above. :-)

[Live example of all of the above](http://jsbin.com/esegot/2)

Comment: @jAndy: Not a bad idea, and certainly we know Chrome has `Function#bind`. But you nee that `0` at the end to be `console`.

Comment: `var e = Function.prototype.call.bind( console.info.bind(console), 0 );`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: infact, you need two `.bind()` calls to make it work, sucks. but I'll leave it for academic reasons :)

Comment: @jAndy: No, just the one does it. See the updated answer, and thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I'm confused now. What does that mean? We are passing the `console` object to `console.info` as first parameter?

Comment: might be worth mentioning that it is trivial to implement bind in non ES5 compatible browsers

Comment: @jAndy: :-) You got **me** confused there. :-) The `e = Function.prototype.call.bind(console.info, console);` version worked, but of course the much, much, *much* more direct route is `e = console.info.bind(console);`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: ya ya you're right. I was just experimenting with some crazy calling conventions to prevent `.call()` and `.apply()` constructs entirely. So I was still into that ^^

Comment: @jAndy: :-) Gotcha. Thanks again for reminding me about `Function#bind`.

Comment: you guys are confused :O i'm freakin lost now :P console an object in the browsers dom for compatible browsers with ES5. But the object needs its parameters to function correctly. Or there abouts?

Comment: @JamieHutber: See the links in the question for the `this` explanation. Re `bind`: In ES5, true JavaScript functions have a `[bind](http://es5.github.com/#x15.3.4.5)` property which refers to a function that accepts the object to use as `this` (and optional other arguments) and returns a function that, when called, will call the original function with `this` as the object you gave. So `f = foo.bind(o);` creates a function and assigns it to the `f` variable which, when called, will call `foo` with `this` set to `o`. Some host-provided functions on some browsers aren't true JS functions, though.